# How can I create a temporary Redirect in .htaccess that all browsers adhere to?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, browser-cache, rfc

Multiple variations of this question have been asked, but I can't seem to find a satisfying answer.

I add the following to my .htaccess file

```
Redirect 302 /test1 /test
```

Then browse to the website. I get redirected to /test.
I then remove the redirect, and browse to the website again. In Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer (Latest versions on 2017-04-14) the browsers use the cached redirect, and send me to /test. On Edge, I get /test1.

As mentioned in other questions, this is *kindof* ok, per [the RFC](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3):

```
Since the redirection might be altered on occasion, the client SHOULD continue to use the Request-URI for future requests.
```

Note that "SHOULD" in RFC lingo means that it is advised, but not obligatory. So it is advised *not* to cache the redirect (and hence, go to /test1), but it is *ok* to cache it anyway. I don't understand why browsers would not follow the RFC suggestion here, ...but there's that.

Then there is the 303 Redirect:

```
The 303 response MUST NOT be cached, but the response to the second (redirected) request might be cacheable.
```

I have tested this. given the RFC, this redirect *MUST NOT* (as in *ever*) be cached. Edge and Firefox play nice here, and don't cache it. Internet Explorer and Chrome seem to decide to bluntly ignore the RFC here, and keep on sending me to /test.

Are these known bugs?
Am I misunderstanding the RFC?
Is there *any* way, to make sure my Redirects don't get cached?

Is the only solution using a RewriteRule? Browsers can't cache the target URL's there, because they never see them, and tend to not cache the target location, so this works for me. (Thanks to @Olaf Dietsche)

```
RewriteRule ^test1 /test
```

(In my use-case, I want to redirect something like website.com/file.pdf to another file. There is no HTML page I can add a no-cache parameter to. Users type this URL into their browsers manually)

Comment: If you want to rewrite instead of redirect, check out [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

Comment: Stupid (of me ;) ). I actually got this to work with RewriteRule. I had a habit of using the R flag, but for my use-case *not* using the R flag is even better (since the URL keeps looking "tidy" and doesn't change to the target file). And, browsers don't cache it; perfect! So, my specific problem is solved, but the question about the 303 redirect remains open...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[the RFC](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) (2616) states

> This document has been superseded.

Precisely, it is [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), which explicitly states "Obsoletes: 2616". And in this case the relevant sections are [303 See Other](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.4) and especially [Appendix B. Changes from RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#appendix-B)

> The description of the 303 (See Other) status code has been changed
> to allow it to be cached *if explicit freshness information is given*,
> and a specific definition has been added for a 303 response to GET.
> (Section 6.4.4)

So in some cases, caching a 303 response is allowed.

Comment: Spot on answer. I was *so* hoping I had found a bug in 3 major browsers :) (Kinda knew that would not be the case) So, to complete this answer, I'll conclude that a *real* temporary Redirect is not possible by means of a Redirect. There are *a lot* of websites out there that explain 302's are temporary... it seems they are all wrong (at least, in practice, for most browsers).

Comment: I think a 302 response is still considered temporary, as written in "[6.4.3.  302 Found](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.4.3) - Since the redirection
   might be altered on occasion, the client ought to continue to use the
   effective request URI for future requests.", even though this is not as strong as *must* or *required*, of course.

Comment: That's the big problem I see with it. It is advocated as being temporary, and almost every tutorial out there will tell you it is, but it seems that all browsers except Edge treat it as a 301. So in practice, they are not temporary at all...